# Return 1 if value is 0 without CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a tidier way of doing the below query so that I'm not duplicating my code.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <COMPLICATED CODE THAT RETURNS A SINGLE INT> = 0
THEN 1
ELSE <COMPLICATED CODE THAT RETURNS A SINGLE INT> END
```

Ideally, I would like something like this using an existing function rather than creating my own:

```
SELECT ISVALUE(COMPLICATED CODE THAT RETURNS A SINGLE INT,0,1)
```

Comment: Can't you use a CTE or SubQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN v.val = 0 THEN 1 ELSE v.val END)
FROM . . . CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (<COMPLICATED CODE THAT RETURNS A SINGLE INT>)) v(val);
```

You could also do a series of functions:

```
select coalesce(nullif(<COMPLICATED CODE THAT RETURNS A SINGLE INT>, 0), 1)
```

However, I think `apply` is clearer.  In addition the above will turn `NULL` values into `1` as well as `0`.

Comment: Excellent, that's just what I was after. Many thanks.

Comment: what's that null if?  If the second parameter is 0 it goes to null, then coalesces to 1?  That's simpler than what I use, which is .(1 - ceiling(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float)))) - 
           floor(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float))))))) + 
           x * ceiling(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float)))) - 
           floor(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float))))))

Comment: @cato . . . Yes, you have described how the second method works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CTE (or a subquery) as

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT <COMPLICATED CODE THAT RETURNS A SINGLE INT> AS Value
  FROM ...
)
SELECT CASE WHEN Value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Value END
FROM CTE
```

This way you write the complicated code just once, and then use just the `Value` column.

Comment: you've still got a case statement, although I see the point in that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IIF`:

`SELECT IIF(1 = 1, 'true', 'false')`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql

Comment: Isn't this going to end up with the same duplication where the condition and the false part still both contain the complex code the OP mentions?

Comment: `IIF` in this way will require duplicating the expression in the predicate and false expression, which is what the asker is trying to avoid.

Comment: I seems like IIF is what the second half of the question asks for.

Answer (score -1):

use a sub query, then you can figure out a mathematical formula that acts to give the values you desire, that way you can eliminate actual boolean logic and replace with mathematical functions
an example is

```
SELECT *,(1 - ceiling(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float)))) - 
           floor(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float))))))) + 
           x * ceiling(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float)))) - 
           floor(cos(atan(abs(cast(x as float)))))) as Computed
FROM
( select 0 as x union SELECT 1 X UNION SELECT -.123 UNION SELECT 9.1 UNION SELECT 67000 union select -1) OQ
```